Why does this read into a dictionary unable to see the first column
I'm using the csv dictreader to read in a CSV file and for some reason unknown to me, it's unable to locate the first column by name.
First few lines of dataset
ComputerName,Installation,HostPurpose,Status,Location,MIListener,Attribute,Priority,SslEnabled,ID
wloa2ama,WindowsHost,Controller,Operational,Default,None,,5,FALSE,1131
wloa2ama,WindowsHost,DataProcessor,Operational,Default,None,,5,FALSE,1131
wloa2ama,WindowsHost,,Operational,Default,None,,5,FALSE,1131
wloa29ma,WindowsHost,LoadGenerator,Operational,Default,None,,5,FALSE,1143

Expecting to see the value of the ComputerName
import csv

csv_file = open('LREHosts.csv', mode='r')
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)


line_count = 0
for row in csv_reader:
    print (row["ComputerName"])
    if line_count == 0:
        print(f'{"  ".join(row)}')
        line_count += 1
    print(f'\t{row["ComputerName"]}  {row["Attribute"]}  {row["Status"]}')
    line_count += 1
print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')

Getting an error Index not found when printing ComputerName
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pk48521\git\perf-api-testing\perf-api-linux.py", line 412, in <module>
    ReadHosts()
  File "C:\Users\pk48521\git\perf-api-testing\perf-api-linux.py", line 33, in ReadHosts
    print (row["ComputerName"])
           ~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'ComputerName'


Your code works perfectly for me with that dataset.  There must be something else involved.  Have you done print(row) to see what you're getting?

The error traceback refers to a function named ReadHosts(), which is obviously not from this code.  Please show us the error message from this exact code.

It's good that you posted a short example, but I think you made a mistake somewhere in the code that you left out.

The code shown is the ReadHosts() function in Python.  I just cut off the function def.   The error is associated with this code.

{'ï»¿ComputerName': 'wloa2ama', 'Installation': 'WindowsHost', 'HostPurpose': 'Controller', 'Status': 'Operational', 'Location': 'Default', 'MIListener': 'None', 'Attribute': '', 'Priority': '5', 'SslEnabled': 'FALSE', 'ID': '1131'}
{'ï»¿ComputerName': 'wloa2ama', 'Installation': 'WindowsHost', 'HostPurpose': 'DataProcessor', 'Status': 'Operational', 'Location': 'Default', 'MIListener': 'None', 'Attribute': '', 'Priority': '5', 'SslEnabled': 'FALSE', 'ID': '1131'}

Notice those garbage characters in front of ComputerName?  You need to remove those from the start of the first line of the file.

Shared python code doesn’t show your problem in the comment or the Error message.

the code and the error are all shown.

@jasonharper that was it.   The file doesn't have the characters in it.  Check with a Hex editor.   Does the csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file) do something to the data when it is converted?

If you open the file with the right encoding, the BOM is ignored with encoding="utf-8-sig":
import csv

with open('LREHosts.csv', mode="r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)

Other option, open the file with a text editor like notepad++ or pspad, etc and save the csv without the BOM.
By the way, I recommend to open and close the file. Closing with close() is done automatically, if you use with open().
